# How to restore access to AAD, after leaving organization?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm leaved organization (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/leave-the-organization) and can't access to AAD, my account was single global admin. How can I restore access to my ADD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending if your organisation uses full cloud Active Directory or a hybrid on-premise + Azure Active Directory there's a couple things you might want to do.

- Look at the on-premise AD server and make sure your user is fully present, enabled and given proper permissions.
- Look into Azure Active Directory setup and see that your user has been synched from on-premise or simply created and given the proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **'leave'** an organization if you account global admin.

The leave process is leaving an organization you are a guest user of, which means you are not the global admin of tenant.

For the remove user section, users cannot remove themselves.

In short if you left an organization you can only be invited back in.